# Group the list of dictionary as list of values based on key

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, group-by

Following is the list of dictionary,

```
 [{'12': 'carrom', 'name': 'tom'}, 
 {'7': 'tennis', 'name': 'tom'}, 
 {'5': 'cycling', 'name': 'tom'},
 {'9': 'tennis', 'name': 'sam'}]
```

How to build a list comprehension in the below format?

```
{'tom' : [12,7,5], 'sam' : [9]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the understanding that there are only two keys per dictionary, you will need to loop through each dictionary and append to a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for l in lst:
    # Pop the name key, so we're only left with the other key.
    name_key = l.pop('name')
    # Extract the remaining key from `l`.
    other_key = list(l)[0] 
    d[name_key].append(other_key)

print(d)
# defaultdict(list, {'sam': ['9'], 'tom': ['12', '7', '5']})
```

Note that this iterates *destructively* over your dictionaries. To get `d` as a plain-dict, use

```
d = dict(d)
```

Since `defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict`.

---

Another option is pandas (since you have the library):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(lst).set_index('name')
df
          12        5       7       9
name                                 
tom   carrom      NaN     NaN     NaN
tom      NaN      NaN  tennis     NaN
tom      NaN  cycling     NaN     NaN
sam      NaN      NaN     NaN  tennis

df.notna().dot(df.columns).groupby(level=0).agg(list).to_dict()
# {'sam': ['9'], 'tom': ['12', '7', '5']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to group your list of dictionaries first,

```
from itertools import groupby
groupby_list = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(alist, key=lambda x: x['name'])]
```

That will output a list,

```
[[{'12': 'carrom', 'name': 'tom'},
  {'7': 'tennis', 'name': 'tom'},
  {'5': 'cycling', 'name': 'tom'}],
[{'9': 'tennis', 'name': 'sam'}]]
```

Then you have to get keys of each nested list, and filter the string key by using `isdigit()` method. I combine it in a long comprehension expression which is a little complicated.

```
[{group[0]['name'] : [int(number) for number in list(set().union(*(d.keys() for d in list(group)))) if number.isdigit()]} for group in groupby_list]
```

The result is what you want:

```
[{'tom': [12, 7, 5]}, {'sam': [9]}]
```

Hope this answer will be helpful.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
your_list_name = [i['name'] for i in your_list]
your_list_name 
    ['tom', 'tom', 'tom', 'sam']

your_list_keys = [i.keys() for i in your_list]
your_list_digit_keys = [[item for item in sublist  if item.isdigit()==True] for sublist in your_list_keys]
your_list_digit_keys = [item for sublist in your_list_digit_keys for item in sublist]
your_list_digit_keys = list(map(int, your_list_digit_keys))
your_list_digit_keys
    [12, 7, 5, 9]

my_dict={} # Initializing the dictionary
for i in range(len(your_list_name)):
    key = your_list_name[i]
    if key in my_dict:
        my_dict[key] += [your_list_digit_keys[i]]
    else:
        my_dict[key] = [your_list_digit_keys[i]]

my_dict
    {'sam': [9], 'tom': [12, 7, 5]}
```